# Using list to write values

Tags: r, list

I want to write values into an R list. For this I have created a test program:

```
testWriteToList <- function() {
    for (i in seq(1:10)) {
        x <- i
        y <- i+1

        list <- list(c(x,y))
    }
return(list)
}

(testWriteToList())
```

However, as output I get:

```
[[1]]
[1] 10 11
```

In fact, I want all the ouput in a list. How to do that?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: add `list <- vector(mode = "list" , 0 )` outside your function and inside your function `list<-` should be `list[[i]] <-`. However, depending on what you want to achevie there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your entire loop to `lapply`

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) c(i, i+1))
```